# How to set up an internal website?

Tags: apache, web, wamp

How do I set up a website that's accessible within a small (office) network? I've only worked on localhost (using WAMP) so far and have no idea where to start. Also, is it possible to access that website through a pseudo domain name/alias instead of an IP?

Comment: which OS do you want to use windows or linux? I have used ubuntu server for that. Its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is of topic here - and wil be covered by lots of basic set up tutorials.

It's exactly the same process, except you need to ensure that clients on the lan can connect to the webserver runing on port 80 - i.e. make sure your firewall isn't blocking the access and that apache is listening on the LAN interface address (the default configs are usually to listen on all addresses).

> is it possible to access that website...

Yes - just publish a DNS record for the webserver in your DNS server - or add it to the hosts files on all of the clients.